# How do I create the bookmarks for Project Update Thursday?

Tags: support, faq-proposed

It's time for Project Update Thursday, but the moderator who normally kicks it off is off saving the world or something.  What do I do?

Answer (score 5):

1. Don't panic.
2. Post a "welcome" message:

   > **Welcome to this week's Project Update Thursday** *(or similar)*
3. Wait two hours.
4. Post a "thank you" message:

   > **Thanks for joining us for this week's Project Update Thursday** *(or similar)*
5. Click on the dropdown next to **room** at the top of the right-hand sidebar, then select *create new bookmark*.
6. Click on the "welcome" and "thank you" messages (it doesn't matter which order).
7. Enter the title for the bookmark.  This should be of the form:

   > **Project Update Thursday - yyyy/mm/dd**
8. Click *bookmark* to create the bookmark; you should see a notification bar at the top of the screen to confirm that you created it.
9. Click on **info** at the top of the right-hand sidebar (which opens a new browser tab) then select the **conversations** tab.  The bookmark you just created should be at the top of the list.
10. Right-click on the bookmark, then select *Copy link address* (or the equivalent for your browser).
11. Go back to the original browser tab with the Home Improvement chat, and paste the link into the input box and click *send*
12. Done!

Comment: And if that's too many steps for anyone, feel free to just post "lets start PUT" and "PUT is over" and I can edit the start/finish messages, add a bookmark, yadda yadda, at any later point.

Comment: For posting the bookmark to the chatroom, you don't even have to go to leave the chatroom, just copy the link in the notification at the top of the window after you create the bookmark and paste it as a chat message.

Answer (score 2):

Niall C. got the full method pretty well, but here's the easy method for anyone that's worried about doing it wrong:

1. Have someone say "Welcome to PUT".
2. When it's over, have someone say "Thanks for joining PUT"

That's all I need, really, two chat messages. I can even edit your messages later on to be bold or whatever, so don't worry about formatting or phrasing. And I can create a bookmark at any point in the future, so if you don't want to deal with that step, feel free to skip it. One of us will do it for you.